# Win10 VM random crashes (VirtualBox, Debian11 host) - what else can I try?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, bsod, crash

After some updates (several Windows Update ones in the VM and also a BIOS upgrade at the host PC -- unfortunately both were done the same day so I can't tell which of them caused this problem) the Win10 VM crashes a few minutes after boot, quite randomly (at random moments and with different error codes, running different applications or just leaving it there with no applications opened)

I get logs like this in the `VBox.log` file of that VM:

```
00:03:46.239192 GIM: HyperV: Guest indicates a fatal condition! P0=0x3b P1=0xc0000005 P2=0xfffff8066340f470 P3=0xffffd98b1c2de640 P4=0x0
00:03:46.239872 GIMHv: BugCheck 3b {c0000005, fffff8066340f470, ffffd98b1c2de640, 0}
00:03:46.239873 SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION
00:03:49.161941 AHCI#0: Reset the HBA
00:03:49.161963 VD#0: Cancelling all active requests
00:03:49.162188 AHCI#0: Port 0 reset
00:03:49.163200 VD#0: Cancelling all active requests
00:03:49.624006 VMMDev: vmmDevHeartbeatFlatlinedTimer: Guest seems to be unresponsive. Last heartbeat received 4 seconds ago
00:03:59.390391 VMMDev: Guest Log: VBoxGuest: BugCheck! P0=0x3b P1=0xc0000005 P2=0xfffff8066340f470 P3=0xffffd98b1c2de640 P4=0x0
00:03:59.390548 GIM: HyperV: Reset initiated through MSR
00:03:59.391650 Changing the VM state from 'RUNNING' to 'RESETTING'
00:03:59.394050 GIM: HyperV: Resetting MMIO2 regions and MSRs
00:03:59.394096 PIT: mode=3 count=0x10000 (65536) - 18.20 Hz (ch=0)
```

or

```
00:13:05.795535 GIM: HyperV: Guest indicates a fatal condition! P0=0x1e P1=0xffffffffc0000005 P2=0xfffff8064de1b99c P3=0x0 P4=0xffffffffffffffff
00:13:05.795650 GIMHv: BugCheck 1e {ffffffffc0000005, fffff8064de1b99c, 0, ffffffffffffffff}
00:13:05.795650 KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
00:13:05.795651 P1: ffffffffc0000005 - exception code - STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
00:13:05.795651 P2: fffff8064de1b99c - EIP/RIP
00:13:05.795651 P3: 0000000000000000 - Xcpt param #0
00:13:05.795651 P4: ffffffffffffffff - Xcpt param #1
```

In that log or in the VM's BSOD I get this crash identifiers (I find it really strange that one single problem or change could cause so many different types of errors):

```
SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION
STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
```

I guess that a clean install of Windows 10 would work fine, but I'd like to keep my files, settings, sessions, stored passwords ...

So trying to recover this installation, I tried to:

- Change/remove the VM virtual hardware in many different combinations: since it looks like a problem with hardware or drivers, I tried different display adapters, removed sound, USB, Shared Folders, processor settings, ...
- Boot Windows and try to install all available updates (the monthly 2022-06 one is not yet installed and so is the 21H2 upgrade). They are found and downloaded, but fail to install, with many different error codes (I googled a few of these and tried some suggestions like disabling hibernation or not using Shared Folders, but nothing worked):

```
0x80073701
0x8000ffff
0x80091007
0x8007000d
0xc80003fa
0x80073712
```

- On the host, download the installers for those updates, copy them to the VM and install them: I couldn't find those installers, seems like they don't provide standalone update installers like in Windows XP
- Open Control Panel, Programs, Uninstall updates: the uninstallation never finishes
- Reboot the host PC
- Boot the VM with a Live Linux ISO, and run badblocks: all ok
- Boot the VM with memtester86: no memory errors
- Downgrade VirtualBox from 6.1.34 to 6.1.32 and 6.1.30: same result
- Booting Windows in safe mode: crashes in the same way
- Booting Windows in rescue mode: none of the options worked:

  - I had no system restore points
  - Uninstall Updates failed with a generic error message, probably for the same reason than uninstalling updates from the running Windows environment
  - Reset Windows using the "Keep my files" option. It offers to use a local version of Windows or download it, and both failed with generic error messages
- Use NirSoft BlueScreenView to get more info about the crashes: all crashes show `ntoskrnl.exe` so I couldn't find any information about failing drivers or devices there
- `chkdsk` finds no errors
- `sfc /scannow` says it can't perform the desired operation
- Download Windows 10 ISO file: after clicking on Repair it takes to the same repair environment as if booting the installed Windows system into rescue mode
- Upgrade to Windows 11: booting from the Win11 ISO does not allow to upgrade, only clean install. Upgrading must be done by booting Win10, and running `setup.exe`, but that fails similarly to trying to use Windows Update (seems to start ok but after a few minutes it says that the operation cannot be completed)

Is there even something else to try?

**EDIT:**

- A few days ago I compacted the VDI file with `vboxmanage modifymedium --compact Win10.vdi`, just in case someone knows of any case of this causing corruption in the disk image
- The Win10 installation went 5 months without applying Windows Updates. They were installed automatically each month but pending a restart, and this month the system was restarted and the update finished

Comment: In Windows 10, Start, Settings, Update, Advanced - Recovery:  Do a Windows 10 Reset and Keep Data. This keeps the User Profile. . It runs in place.

Comment: `There was a problem resetting your PC` :(  It's funny how each version of Windows gives less and less details about the internals

Comment: If that does not work, you will need to build a new VM and proceed that way.

Comment: @golimar - Did you always have Hyper-V enabled in the VM?  The firmware update on the host unlikely has anything to do with your problem.  Microsoft absolutely provides standalone installers for updates. You don't specify which updates you couldn't find, some updates can only be downloaded through Windows Update, without knowing what updates you were attempting to install I can't address your concern.

Comment: @Ramhound I think it was always with Hyper-V, but I also tried KVM and others. These are the updates: KB5014666 and KB5014699

Comment: [KB5014699](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/june-14-2022-kb5014699-os-builds-19042-1766-19043-1766-and-19044-1766-5c81d49d-0b6e-4808-9485-1f54e5d1bb15) is this month's cumulative update.  [KB5014666](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/june-28-2022-kb5014666-os-builds-19042-1806-19043-1806-and-19044-1806-preview-4bd911df-f290-4753-bdec-a83bc8709eb6) is a preview update for July's update..  You only need to install one or the other.  Both have installers [here](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/home.aspx)

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, it failed similarly as with Windows Update, but it's good to know where to download those installers

Comment: @golimar do you happen to use zRAM / zswap?

Comment: Also, see https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?p=520036#p520036

Comment: @Shevchuk I'll check it today, but that definitely looks like it, you should create an answer with it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer.
[Similar problem was reported on VirtualBox forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=106388), here is what discussion came to:

> The actual problem is that VirtualBox 6.1.34 and 6.1.97r150532 do not support Debian Linux kernel 5.10.120 on the host and will produce random crashes in the guest (pun intended ;)). See [20914](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/20914) and [Windows 10 Guest on Linux host dies seconds after boot for details](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=106071).
>
> The [VirtualBox test builds](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds) 6.1.35r151864 (and newer) are supposed to support Linux kernels 5.18, 5.17.12+, 5.15.44+, 5.10.119+ and more on the host and in the guest.

---

As a side note, I have experienced unpredictable VirtualBox guests behavior on hosts with zRAM (no such issues with KVM), so check that, too.

Comment: I had searched that forum by keyword and found nothing. Sometimes it's better to just check the last posts just in case your keywords were not the right ones!

Comment: Also, VirtualBox should at least mention in the Downloads page that Test Builds are available...

Comment: I had same issue with Ubuntu 22.04.1 using kernel 5.15 and virtualbox 6.1.34 offered by ubuntu repos: Random application chrashes in the Windows 10 guest OS and sometimes random reboots. I upgraded to virtualbox 6.1.38 from the official oracle repository and so far it's been very stable.

Comment: virtualbox 6.1.38 is now available in the Ubuntu repos

Comment: just experience the same phenomenon with Ubuntu 22.04.1 and vb 6.1.34. vm starts with a boot loop, occasionally offers to "repair". I checked that I had started the vm without problems after upgrading to 22.04. similar to OP, I had removed a couple of snapshots (from the VB UI) before the problems occurred. upgrading to 6.1.38 resolved the issues

Answer (score 1):

Try to copy your virtual machine to another PC and see if it runs there. That will tell you if the host machine or the virtual machine is the issue:

- If it's the VM - refresh windows keeping your data. You can also create a second (new) vm and copy your data from one to the other.
- if it runs fine, its your hardware... fix that. Undo your bios upgrade or whatever.